# Add 2 frameworks inside another new framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

I'm trying to generate a swift framework which integrates 2 smaller frameworks developed in objective-c. The idea is to wrap them in order to be able to use them adding only the new framework in a Swift 5 project.

1. Can I generate it by only adding those 2 frameworks?
2. Maybe doing some Swift code which does some middle work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these steps:

1.- Created SDK project.
2.- Inserted both frameworks
3.- In the .h file, added imports to make them public.
4.- Added swift code configurating classes and function as public (most important step)
5.- When swift code was working, deleted in the .h file the imports in order to make both frameworks unaccesibles.

Hope this will help.